# Paragon NTFS doesn't work on enforcing mode

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mount, ntfs

I need to mount 2TB SeaGate external HD to my Galaxy S4 LTE, and I'm using Paragon NTFS for that. The app worked when I was still using EchoeROM. I recently switched to Paranoid 4.4.4 and now this app won't work.

Is there any way to make it work again?

Comment: You'd need to add a lot more details to your question, for example what device you're using, which version of Paranoid, what apps are you trying to use to access the drive...

Comment: Ok i added the details. Please help me now.

Comment: Does the app give an error message? Did you try mounting other drives? Have you checked that you have all the requirements for the app, mainly fuse kernel module?

Comment: Yes. It says that it doesn't work on enforcing mode.